# Troubleshooting Resource Governor / Classification Function

Tags: sql-server, dmv, resource-governor

I've been trying to configure / troubleshoot the resource governor on a sql server 2014 instance. I can't get any work into anything but the default resource pool. I've been following this troubleshooting guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627395(v=sql.105).aspx

My classification function, originally conditional, now simply returns my resource pool name in all cases in an attempt to get something to run in it.

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[RGClassifier]    Script Date: 7/25/2014 7:26:51 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RGClassifier] ()
RETURNS sysname
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @GroupName SYSNAME
SET @GroupName = N'in-memory'

RETURN @GroupName

END
```

Results of some of the troubleshooting follow:

```
USE master
SELECT 
  object_schema_name(classifier_function_id) AS [schema_name],
  object_name(classifier_function_id) AS [function_name]
FROM sys.dm_resource_governor_configuration
```

Returns:

```
schema_name function_name
dbo RGClassifier
```

Queries of sys.dm_resource_governor_configuration and sys.resource_governor_configuration indicate it is enabled and no reconfiguration is pending.

More or less stuck in the mud at this point. If anyone has configured the resource governor successfully before I'd love some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your group name returned matches (identically) to your actual workload group name. Some times, I've found, it's helpful to reconfigure even if it doesn't say it needs to be done.

```
use master
GO

-- Create a test DB which our CF will be based on
CREATE DATABASE RGDB;
GO

-- enable RG
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RGClassifier()
RETURNS sysname
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    IF (ORIGINAL_DB_NAME() = 'RGDB')
        RETURN N'OriginalDBWG'

    RETURN N'Default'
END
GO

-- Create a new Pool
CREATE RESOURCE POOL OriginalDBPool
WITH (
MAX_CPU_PERCENT = 10
)
GO

--Create a new WG
CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP OriginalDBWG USING OriginalDBPool
GO

ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR WITH ( CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION = dbo.RGClassifier)
GO

ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Open a new query window after running this and check the pool name by running:

```
SELECT wg.name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s inner join sys.dm_resource_governor_workload_groups wg on s.group_id = wg.group_id where s.session_id = @@SPID
```

Then, change the connection and add in an additional parameter

```
database=RGDB;
```

Then run the query again. You should see the workload group name change.

Comment: Haha oh wow. Somehow I missed the fact that the function is to return the workload group name NOT the resource pool name. Thanks!